# Android Testing - How to validate navController.currentDestination.arguments?

Tags: android, testing, casting, navigation, android-espresso

I am trying to validate the data passed to my new fragment using espresso and navigation component.
I grabbed an example from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing) to simplify this question.

```
@Test
fun testNavigationToInGameScreen() {
    // Create a TestNavHostController
    val navController = TestNavHostController(
        ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.trivia)

    // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TitleScreen>()

    // Set the NavController property on the fragment
    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }

    // Verify that performing a click changes the NavController’s state
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.play_btn)).perform(ViewActions.click())
    assertThat(navController.currentDestination?.id).isEqualTo(R.id.in_game)

    // HERE IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO VALIDATE ARGUMENTS
    val currentDestinationArgs = navController.currentDestination.arguments
    val expectedArguments = bundleOf(ARG_A to true)

    assertEquals(currentDestinationArgs, expectedArguments)
}
```

I can't figure out how to cast `currentDestinationArgs` to a bundle for validating the
`currentDestinationArgs`. The `currentDestinationArgs` field is a `MutableMap<String, NavArgument>` from what I can tell.
Has someone figured out how to test this kind of thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bundle doesn't implement equals anyways, so you have to check whether each key exists in any case.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I wrote it like this so you guys could understand what I'm trying to do, I mainly just want to cast this `currentDestinationArgs` into a usable object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`currentDestination` isn't the right API - that returns the `NavDestination` from your graph representing the current destination.

What you actually want to look at is the [backStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController#backstack):

```
// Get the arguments from the last destination on the back stack
val currentDestinationArgs = navController.backStack.last().arguments

// Use the Truth extension on Bundle from androidx.test.ext:truth:1.3.0-rc01
assertThat(currentDestinationArgs).bool(ARG_A).isTrue()
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've spent way too much time on this! <3

Comment: Actual life-saver!

Comment: Please consider adding this to the documentation. Thanks.